# C/C++ print custom EOL

Tags: c++, c, printf, output, eol

I want to generate on Windows a file (script) for UNIX. So I need to output just `LF` characters, without outputting `CR` characters.

When I do `fprintf(fpout, "some text\n");`, character `\n` is automatically replaced by `\r\n` in the file.

Is there a way to output specifically just `\n` (`LF`) character?

The language is C++, but the I/O functions come from C.

Comment: A workaround would be to use [putchar()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/putchar/), if no easy solution exists.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can open the file in binary mode, e.g.

```
FILE *fpout = fopen("unixfile.txt", "wb");

fprintf(fpout, "some text\n"); // no \r inserted before \n
```

As a consequence, every byte you pass to `fprintf` is interpreted as a byte and nothing else, which should omit the conversion from `\n` to `\r\n`.

From cppreference on [std::fopen](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen):

> File access mode flag "b" can optionally be specified to open a file in binary mode. This flag has no effect on POSIX systems, but on Windows, for example, it disables special handling of '\n' and '\x1A'.

Comment: This question is an awesome coincidence, I just read about exactly this _yesterday_ in Arthur O'Dwyer's STL book. The author also made no effort to hide his opinion on how Windows handles newlines.